# WiFi does not work anymore

Tags: wifi, internet

I installed elementary OS on a hp laptop, and everything was working fine. Suddenly, after 3 days Internet connection does not work anymore. The laptop connects to the WiFi, but Internet won't work. I installed Elementary in dual boot, and when using Windows the laptop connects to the Internet normally...

Answer (score 0):

I solved by overwriting the resolv.conf file with only two lines:
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

Now I fear I shouldn't have completely overwritten the file with only those two lines. I'm completely new to Linux; do you think it will generate more problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no problem because this file gets overwritten if you reconnect to your wifi. However, it seems that your wifi router is not configured well enough to provide the actual DNS server to elementary OS.